# How to find virtualenv location for ipykernel

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

How do I find the directory location of a python3 virtualenv, where I have previously installed an ipythonn kernel? I often run into this issue where I need to install more packages for a particular kernel in jupyter notebook, but can't seem to find where I have created the virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

Going through jupyter docs, I found this:

List available kernelspec

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

which looks like this

```
myenv             /Users/johnappleseed/Library/Jupyter/kernels/myenv
...               ...
```

Go to kernelspec directory and directory to virtualenv is in kernel.json

```
cat /Users/johnappleseed/Library/Jupyter/kernels/myenv/kernel.json
```